# blackberry simulator not working properly on my mac with wine

Tags: blackberry-simulator

blackberry simulator not working properly on my mac with wine. BB Curve 8320 simulator v.4.2.2 & v.4.3.
It installs and launches but comes up with various errors: DE365s errors, password record not found, incompatible or corrupt password structure, flash failure - DE361 error, JVM Error 548 flash erase failed.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't get this to work. I had to resort to my windows installation  on my mac using Parallels Desktop.